# Convert MongoDB entry to Java Class Model Object

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo

I am storing a custom java object called `Device` into a mongo collection. This works fine. But when I am receiving the database entry all inner class objects are assigned with `null` and not with the database value.

This is a device:

```
public class Device {

    public String id;

    public String serialNumber;

    public String name;

    public int status;

    public String errorReport;

    public List<Sensor> sensors=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Action> actions=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> filterTags= new ArrayList<>();

    public List protocols;
}
```

This is an example entry from the database, as you can see the values are saved well:

```
    {
        "_id": "7_openHabsamsungtv:tv:cbaf7d7d_4e10_41e6_9c1d_864988057bda",
        "actions": [
            {
                "_id": "samsungtv:tv:cbaf7d7d_4e10_41e6_9c1d_864988057bda:volume",
                "deviceId": "7_openHabsamsungtv:tv:cbaf7d7d_4e10_41e6_9c1d_864988057bda",
                "errorReport": "Value wurde nicht initialisiert",
                "name": "Lautst�rke",
                "state": 0,
                "value": 0,
                "valueOption": {
                    "maximum": 0,
                    "minimum": 0,
                    "percentage": true
                },
                "valueable": true
            }
    ],
    "filterTags": [],
        "name": "[TV] Chine ",
        "sensors": [
            {
                "_id": "samsungtv:tv:cbaf7d7d_4e10_41e6_9c1d_864988057bda:sourceId",
                "name": "Source ID"
            },
            {
                "_id": "samsungtv:tv:cbaf7d7d_4e10_41e6_9c1d_864988057bda:programTitle",
                "name": "Titel"
            },
            {
                "_id": "samsungtv:tv:cbaf7d7d_4e10_41e6_9c1d_864988057bda:channelName",
                "name": "Kanal"
            }
        ],
        "status": 0
    }
```

And this is what it looks like when I am receiving it from the database again:

```
{
        "id": "7_openHabsamsungtv:tv:cbaf7d7d_4e10_41e6_9c1d_864988057bda",
        "serialNumber": null,
        "name": "[TV] Chine ",
        "status": 0,
        "errorReport": null,
        "sensors": [
            {
                "id": null,
                "name": null,
                "errorReport": null
            },
            {
                "id": null,
                "name": null,
                "errorReport": null
            },
            {
                "id": null,
                "name": null,
                "errorReport": null
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "id": null,
                "name": null,
                "deviceId": null,
                "state": 0,
                "states": null,
                "valueOption": null,
                "value": 0,
                "errorReport": "Value wurde nicht initialisiert",
                "valueable": false
            }
],
        "filterTags": [],
        "protocols": null
    }
```

So when I am pulling the entries from my db collection it sets the values of the `Sensor` and `Action` to null. This is my Java Code for receiving a device:

```
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI(dummy);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
MongoCollection<Device> devices = database.withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry).getCollection("devices", Device.class);

Device device = devices.find().first();
```

I am using the standard MongoDB Java Driver.
Could anyone tell me what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use [Morphia](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/) ORM like Hibernate for relational SQL databases.

Comment: Because I thought the light standard library would be sufficient. So is there no way without any other libraries?

Comment: what about he filterTags list, is it filled correctly? 
Also, could you please provide one mongodb document for us to reproduce?

Comment: @GeorgMuehlenberg yes the filtertags list is filled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You need setters and getters per default config.

I wrote this Unit-Test to reproduce the error, but it does not reproduce except when I play around with the Action and Sensor classes. I am using Mongodb 3.4 and Java driver 3.6.

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class MongoDeser {

    @Test
    public void testDeser() {
        MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("sotest");
        PojoCodecProvider codecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                .automatic(true)
                .build();

        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), fromProviders(codecProvider));

        MongoCollection<Device> devices = database.withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry).getCollection("device", Device.class);

        Device device = devices.find().first();

        assertNotNull(device.getActions());
        assertThat(device.getActions().size(), is(1));
        assertThat(device.getActions().get(0).getDeviceId(), is("7_openHabsamsungtv:tv:cbaf7d7d_4e10_41e6_9c1d_864988057bda"));
        assertThat(device.getStatus(), is(0));
        assertThat(device.getName(), is("[TV] Chine "));
    }

}
```

## Do you have missing getters and/or setters in your POJOs?

Mongodb Java driver [uses reflection](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/bson/pojos/) for mapping POJOs from BSON. It needs these Getters and Setters per default configuration. If you don't have them, it may behave erratically. In my testing, sometimes it couldn't find a codec and threw an exception, sometimes the fields were just nulled as in your case. My recommendation would be to use annotations instead and give the Java driver a convention for it.

#### Sensor class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Sensor implements Serializable
{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 8244091126694748358L;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

#### Action class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Action implements Serializable
{

    private String id;
    private String deviceId;
    private String errorReport;
    private String name;
    private long state;
    private long value;
    private ValueOption valueOption;
    private boolean valueable;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 3493217442158516855L;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public String getErrorReport() {
        return errorReport;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public long getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public ValueOption getValueOption() {
        return valueOption;
    }

    public boolean isValueable() {
        return valueable;
    }

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public void setErrorReport(String errorReport) {
        this.errorReport = errorReport;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setState(long state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void setValue(long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValueOption(ValueOption valueOption) {
        this.valueOption = valueOption;
    }

    public void setValueable(boolean valueable) {
        this.valueable = valueable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is correct, because I can't see any Sensor or Action class in your code.

Comment: I am adding them to my answer.

Comment: from where are you getting serialVersionUID?

Comment: it worked, I did not have setters for the properties

Comment: For the serialVersionUID, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Answer (score -1):

```
CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
CodecRegistries.fromProviders(new pojoCodecRegistryCodecProvider()),
CodecRegistries.fromProviders(new ActionCodecProvider()),
CodecRegistries.fromProviders(new SensorCodecProvider()));
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)